Translate from MongoDB's mongosh JSON syntax to go?
In the Mongo shell, I'm able to run a query with the following syntax:
db.collection.find(query, projection, options)

Is there a way for me to use the golang Mongo driver to make a query in the same format, by passing 3 JSON (or bson) objects into a function? It seems like in go, in order to set a limit, I'd have to say:
opts := options.Find().SetLimit(2)

But I'd prefer to  be able to call:
coll.Find(context.TODO(), query, projection, bson.M{"limit": 2})

This would let me avoid translating queries from one syntax to another. Is there an option in the go driver to do this?

No, there is not. You have to follow the driver's API.

You can of course write a "wrapper" or helper functions to which you pass those 3 objects, which then translates them to the driver's API.
